# How to apply order by Window function in DAX

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

In PowerBI, I want to create a calculated table from table `t`. Using DAX, how can I write the equivalent of the following SQL query. Basically, here I am finding running sum (`cumsum`) using cnt ordered by date.

```
select
    date,
    cnt,
    sum(cnt) over (order by date) as cumsum
from
    t
```

This is an example output. The source table has columns `d` and `cnt`. This query adds the table `cumsum`.

```
date, cnt, cumsum
2022-01-01, 13, 13,
2022-01-02, 14, 27
2022-01-03, 18, 45
...
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and expected output?

Comment: @DavidBacci Added a sample output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

Table1 :

[image]

Table2:

[image]

```
Table2 = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(Table1, Table1[date], Table1[cnt]),
    "cumsum", 
    VAR x= Table1[date]
    RETURN
    CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[cnt]), REMOVEFILTERS(), Table1[date] <= x )
)
```